# Checking logged-in user info on CakePHP when using a custom auth adapter

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, jwt

I'm using [this JWTAuth adapter](https://github.com/t73biz/cakephp2-jwt-auth) to use JWT authentication instead of cookie-based auth in my CakePHP 2.8 app. It works great, except for one hitch:

Normally for one of my REST endpoints, I can use `$this->Auth->user("id")` to get the currently logged-in users' ID.

When I try to make a controller action accessible to non-members using `$this->Auth->allow()`, a problem occurs. If I do this, using `$this->Auth->loggedIn()` in the controller returns `false`, meaning I can not add additional logic for logged-in users.

**When using standard cookie auth:**

- `$this->Auth->user('id')` is available in
  `Controller::beforeFilter()`.
- `$this->Auth->loggedIn()` is `true` in
  `Controller::beforeFilter()`.
- `$this->Auth->user('id')` is available in controller actions, public
  and members-only.
- `$this->Auth->loggedIn()` is `true` in controller actions, public
  and members-only.

**When using JWT auth:**

- `$this->Auth->user('id')` is `null` in `Controller::beforeFilter()`.
- `$this->Auth->loggedIn()` is `false` in
  `Controller::beforeFilter()`.
- `$this->Auth->user('id')` is available in members-only controller actions, and `null` in public controller actions.
- `$this->Auth->loggedIn()` is `true` in members-only controller actions, and `false` in public controller actions.

Is there any way I can get Auth to include information returned by the JWTAuth component on actions that have been made public by `$this->Auth->allow()`?

**Example controller here:**

```
public function visible(){
    // This will always be false, even if a valid JWT token is sent
    $this->set("loggedIn", $this->Auth->loggedIn());
}

public function members_only(){
    // This will be unavailable if not logged in, and a true if logged in
    $this->set("loggedIn", $this->Auth->loggedIn());
}

public function beforeFilter($options = array()){
    parent::beforeFilter();

    $this->Auth->allow("visible");
}
```

**And for reference, my AppController::components array;**

```
public $components = array(
    'DebugKit.Toolbar',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authorize' => array(
            'Actions' => array(
                'actionPath' => 'controllers'
            ),
        ),
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email'),
                'contain' => array(
                    'UserProfile',
                )
            ),
            'JwtAuth.JwtToken' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'token' => 'password',
                ),
                'header' => 'AuthToken',
                'userModel' => 'User',
            ),
        ),
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => false
    ),
    "Acl",
    "RequestHandler",
    "Session"
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit late, but I found a solution to this problem, but (warning!) it involved updating the code for AuthComponent.

I took a copy of Lib/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php and placed it under app/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php.

I then added one line to the file:

```
public function startup(Controller $controller) {
    $methods = array_flip(array_map('strtolower', $controller->methods));
    $action = strtolower($controller->request->params['action']);

    // One-line modification from the ordinary CakePHP file.
    // This lets us have info on the logged-in user in public actions when using stateless auth.
    $this->_getUser();
```

Voila, you can now access user info on the server while accessing a non-protected controller function with stateless auth!

Comment: There is already condition to check `_getuser()` so just adding this line make no difference and it still not identifying user in `beforefilter` Is there any additional config?

Comment: Hi Kenana, I do not know what stateless auth system you are working with. You can use this approach (patching AuthComponent) to find what modifications you may need to make!

Comment: @caitlin please avoid updating source code, because you will loose the changes when you upgrade your cake version. Instead try my solution.

Comment: @Farhan When you make the change as I did, the change won't get overwritten when you upgrade your lib. I don't see your solution. Did you post it here?

Comment: @caitlin you can initialize auth component in your beforeFilter() as
$this->Auth->startup($this);

Answer (score 4):

For stateless adapters authentication process is triggerd in `AuthComponent::startup()`. Component's `startup()` methods are run **after** `Controller::beforeFilter()`, that is why `AuthComponent::user()` doesn't return any info.

For other adapters when user is authenticated the identity info is stored in session. Getting that info doesn't require any authentication process which is why `AuthComponent::user()` give you the user info in case of standard cookie based auth.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that in CakePHP 3.x the AuthComponent can be configured to run the authentication process in it's `initialize()` method which is run before controller's `beforeFilter()`.

Comment: What about` Cakephp 2` How can i get user info in `beforeFilter`? I think this solution is only for `Cakephp 3`

Comment: @KenanaReda Please see my answer- I found a solution!